# Shuffle deck of cards in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting, ecmascript-6, playing-cards, shuffle

I know randomness in programming can be a deep topic, and searching the topic seems to result in Fisher-Yates being the best method, but I'm curious what people would say about this method.

Basically, since I have the cards as objects, I just add a property of a random number then sort the entire array based on those random numbers.

```js
const suits = [
  {
    digit: 'H',
    word: 'hearts'
  },
  {
    digit: 'C',
    word: 'clubs'
  },
  {
    digit: 'D',
    word: 'diamonds'
  },
  {
    digit: 'S',
    word: 'spades'
  }
]
const cardsWithoutSuits = [
  {
    numeric: 1,
    word: 'ace',
    digit: 'A'
  },
  {
    numeric: 2,
    word: 'two',
  },
  {
    numeric: 3,
    word: 'three',
  },
  {
    numeric: 4,
    word: 'four',
  },
  {
    numeric: 5,
    word: 'five',
  },
  {
    numeric: 6,
    word: 'six',
  },
  {
    numeric: 7,
    word: 'seven',
  },
  {
    numeric: 8,
    word: 'eight',
  },
  {
    numeric: 9,
    word: 'nine',
  },
  {
    numeric: 10,
    word: 'ten',
  },
  {
    numeric: 11,
    word: 'jack',
    digit: 'J'
  },
  {
    numeric: 12,
    word: 'queen',
    digit: 'Q'
  },
  {
    numeric: 13,
    word: 'king',
    digit: 'K'
  }
]

function createDeck(decks = 1){
  let deck = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < decks; i++) {
    suits.forEach( x => {
      cardsWithoutSuits.forEach( y => {
        deck.push({
          numeric: y.numeric,
          word: y.word,
          suit: x.word,
          phrase: `${y.word} of ${x.word}`,
          abbr: `${y.hasOwnProperty('digit') ? y.digit : y.numeric}${x.digit}`
        })
      })
    })
  }
  return deck;
}

function shuffle(array){
  array.forEach( x =>{
    x.ran = Math.random();
  })
  array.sort( (a, b) =>{
    return a.ran - b.ran;
  })

  return array;
}

let deck = shuffle(createDeck(2));
console.log(deck);
```

Comment: Here is a version in codepen: https://codepen.io/LouBagel/pen/WPrzjy

Comment: The time complexity of this algorithm is `O(n*lg(n))` while Fisher-Yates and friends are linear in n.  And a big problem with pseudo-random number generators as shufflers is that they have far fewer possible permutations than a deck of cards.  52 factorial is about 8e67; compare to [Chrome's Math.random()](https://v8.dev/blog/math-random) with 128 bits of internal state - about 3e38 possible states.  For a given real-world deck ordering, the odds are only about 1 in  a nonillion that your algorithm can produce it in a better-than-average JavaScript engine.

Comment: @OhMyGoodness The size of the random does not limit the permutations, rather it limits the length of a sequence without a predictable repeating pattern.; Games of chance play with as little as 1 bit (coin) yet will still require a sufficiently large PRNG to ensure the game can not be exploited. With dedication, an unaided human will be hard pushed to identify pattern from a  16bit PRNG

Comment: @Blindman67 2^128 seeds cannot yield more than 2^128 distinct initial sequences of 52 numbers from a deterministic algorithm.   2^128 <<< 52!, the end.   Unless you're saying we don't need to use the *first* 52 numbers?  Which is true, but you have to choose which 52 to use, somehow, and it has to be unpredictable, and if you can choose 52 things unpredictably, just make those things be "cards" instead of "PRNG cycles" and then you don't need the PRNG at all.

Answer (score 1):

There has already been some discussion by [@Oh My Goodness](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/131732/oh-my-goodness) and [@Blindman67](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/120556/blindman67) in the comments about the time complexity of this code vs Fisher-Yates. I don't really have much to add to that discussion but will offer some suggestions about the code on a deeper level below.

Like I mentioned in [my answer to your post *Simple math game in JavaScript*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/194958/120114) some variable names could more accurately hint at the semantic meaning of the value - for example, instead of `x.ran = Math.random();`, a name like `sortVal` would hint that the value is to be used for sorting.

```
array.forEach( x =>{
  x.sortVal = Math.random();
})
```

---

The arrow function in the `shuffle()` method is quite short and thus can be simplified to a single line:

```
array.sort( (a, b) => a.sortVal - b.sortVal)
```

The `forEach` block above it could also be simplified:

```
array.forEach( x => x.sortVal = Math.random())
```

In this case, `x.sortVal` would be returned in each iteration but that doesn't make a difference.

---

The Array sort method [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) returns the array so the `shuffle()` function could be simplified to have the `return` statement on the same line as the call to that method:

```
  return array.sort( (a, b) => a.sortVal - b.sortVal)
```

---

Additionally, any value that doesn't get re-assigned could be declared using `const`, which would help avoid any unintentional re-assignment - e.g. `deck` within `shuffle()`, and `deck` at the end of the code.